# system is computationally singular in NbClust

Tags: r

I'm trying to cluster my data using kmeans clustering. I have done it before using other code, and the silhouette method specifically, but I wanted to check using all the methods which cluster number is the best to use. So, technically I already have the results I need, but I'm trying to figure out the best number of clusters.

Here is my data:

```
 > dput(test_HR)
structure(c(0.62791839709163, 0.269727484328178, -2.74490538275433, 
-0.433503753992933, 0.34137640199046, 0.315043891365162, 0.0999238703922213, 
0.680853497067473, 0.150093380184488, -0.308327958912585, 1.00180017324024, 
1.21729797864757, 0.436782201581825, -0.694171008161157, -1.19996858490696, 
0.0909173815409863, -0.119567411383651, -0.980382506336439, 0.0271584302438771, 
-1.09154681886507, 0.275380685709451, 2.03809965192957, 1.19853346965137, 
-0.783159342324781, 1.31547170875921, -1.25786980767569, 0.107179311435179, 
1.59923657488184, -0.428918046549936, 0.145187156591745, -1.13861076036333, 
-0.00410247418210791, -0.752947790223482, 0.331635978858542, 
-0.324698697091408, -0.366939809732035, 1.87665583021329, 0.234018035616217, 
-1.88973740319185, 0.304573827357716, -1.3122760733046, 0.789356452479366, 
0.163779874584177, 0.193631984210588, 0.262369629688167, 0.513192521639039, 
1.20911405348457, -1.63994819724652, -0.15410653315565, 0.834605489724827, 
-0.213044221933932, 0.379666284804451, -1.99792597367362, 0.783808112061816, 
0.0222688346068515, -0.475968393267285, -0.151980243723096, 2.50353666340212, 
-1.17250267210696, -0.982006378303119, 0.145088511549469, 0.78621669206514, 
-0.521330762941883, 0.252756648877046, 0.0260939256941625, -0.409903991245595, 
-0.972649726261851, -0.478366116085223, 1.114624003624, 1.48057579301951, 
-0.25404810483649, -0.106236918175294, 0.483170285186188, -0.0791622856588665, 
1.07299291691395, -0.303427479829247, -1.95747236789668), dim = c(11L, 
7L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("LagAir", "LagRadiation", "LagWind", 
"Precip", "RainingTRUE", "Intercept", "Interaction")), "`scaled:center`" = c(LagAir = 0.0529109494963645, 
LagRadiation = -0.000637961323390131, LagWind = 0.0227735745358962, 
Precip = -0.00560170484771019, RainingTRUE = 0.0459079898931734, 
Intercept = 1.49834735849528, Interaction = 3.13819794343619e-05
), "`scaled:scale`" = c(LagAir = 0.0222479701056984, LagRadiation = 0.00147802416540991, 
LagWind = 0.0283265776701396, Precip = 0.0231062355647722, RainingTRUE = 0.166664243248577, 
Intercept = 0.42361640647579, Interaction = 5.85604077225175e-05
))
```

It's already been scaled. Each row is a different individual that I'm trying to cluster.

This is the code that I'm running on the data.

```
cluster_test_HR <- NbClust(test_HR, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 8, method = "kmeans", index = "all")
```

But, when I do that, I get this error:

```
Error in solve.default(W) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.01834e-16
In addition: Warning message:
In log(det(P)/det(W)) : NaNs produced
```

Can someone explain to me what that means and how I can fix it?

Thank you.